# View is black, when going back in the navigationcontrollers stack of views, after implementing custom transition

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift4

I have a tableview with a list of elements. I've tried to implement a zoom transition to the detailview, when tapping a cell in the tableview.
The transition works as intended - but when I press "back", i'm taken to a black view.

I'm new to working with custom transitions, so maybe there's something that I'm missing - I'm just not sure what. I followed this article: https://blog.rocketinsights.com/how-to-create-a-navigation-transition-like-the-apple-news-app/ to make the zoomtransition, and converted the code to Swift 4.

Here's my zoomtransition class:

```
class ZoomTransitionAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    private let duration: TimeInterval = 0.5
    var operation: UINavigationControllerOperation = .push
    var thumbnailFrame = CGRect.zero

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return duration
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        let presenting = operation == .push

        // Determine which is the master view and which is the detail view that we're navigating to and from. The container view will house the views for transition animation.
        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        guard let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.to) else { return }
        guard let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: UITransitionContextViewKey.from) else { return }
        let storyFeedView = presenting ? fromView : toView
        let storyDetailView = presenting ? toView : fromView

        // Determine the starting frame of the detail view for the animation. When we're presenting, the detail view will grow out of the thumbnail frame. When we're dismissing, the detail view will shrink back into that same thumbnail frame.
        var initialFrame = presenting ? thumbnailFrame : storyDetailView.frame
        let finalFrame = presenting ? storyDetailView.frame : thumbnailFrame

        // Resize the detail view to fit within the thumbnail's frame at the beginning of the push animation and at the end of the pop animation while maintaining it's inherent aspect ratio.
        let initialFrameAspectRatio = initialFrame.width / initialFrame.height
        let storyDetailAspectRatio = storyDetailView.frame.width / storyDetailView.frame.height
        if initialFrameAspectRatio > storyDetailAspectRatio {
            initialFrame.size = CGSize(width: initialFrame.height * storyDetailAspectRatio, height: initialFrame.height)
        }
        else {
            initialFrame.size = CGSize(width: initialFrame.width, height: initialFrame.width / storyDetailAspectRatio)
        }

        let finalFrameAspectRatio = finalFrame.width / finalFrame.height
        var resizedFinalFrame = finalFrame
        if finalFrameAspectRatio > storyDetailAspectRatio {
            resizedFinalFrame.size = CGSize(width: finalFrame.height * storyDetailAspectRatio, height: finalFrame.height)
        }
        else {
            resizedFinalFrame.size = CGSize(width: finalFrame.width, height: finalFrame.width / storyDetailAspectRatio)
        }

        // Determine how much the detail view needs to grow or shrink.
        let scaleFactor = resizedFinalFrame.width / initialFrame.width
        let growScaleFactor = presenting ? scaleFactor: 1/scaleFactor
        let shrinkScaleFactor = 1/growScaleFactor

        if presenting {
            // Shrink the detail view for the initial frame. The detail view will be scaled to CGAffineTransformIdentity below.
            storyDetailView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: shrinkScaleFactor, y: shrinkScaleFactor)
            storyDetailView.center = CGPoint(x: thumbnailFrame.midX, y: thumbnailFrame.midY)
            storyDetailView.clipsToBounds = true
        }

        // Set the initial state of the alpha for the master and detail views so that we can fade them in and out during the animation.
        storyDetailView.alpha = presenting ? 0 : 1
        storyFeedView.alpha = presenting ? 1 : 0

        // Add the view that we're transitioning to to the container view that houses the animation.
        containerView.addSubview(toView)
        containerView.bringSubview(toFront: storyDetailView)

        // Animate the transition.
        UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
            // Fade the master and detail views in and out.
            storyDetailView.alpha = presenting ? 1 : 0
            storyFeedView.alpha = presenting ? 0 : 1

            if presenting {
                // Scale the master view in parallel with the detail view (which will grow to its inherent size). The translation gives the appearance that the anchor point for the zoom is the center of the thumbnail frame.
                let scale = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: growScaleFactor, y: growScaleFactor)
                let translate = storyFeedView.transform.translatedBy(x: storyFeedView.frame.midX - self.thumbnailFrame.midX, y: storyFeedView.frame.midY - self.thumbnailFrame.midY)
                storyFeedView.transform = translate.concatenating(scale)
                storyDetailView.transform = .identity
            }
            else {
                // Return the master view to its inherent size and position and shrink the detail view.
                storyFeedView.transform = .identity
                storyDetailView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: shrinkScaleFactor, y: shrinkScaleFactor)
            }

            // Move the detail view to the final frame position.
            storyDetailView.center = CGPoint(x: finalFrame.midX, y: finalFrame.midY)
        }) { finished in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(finished)
        }
    }

}
```

In my main viewcontroller I've implemented the UINavigationControllerDelegate, with the following code:

```
extension SearchVC: UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationControllerOperation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        if operation == .push {

            //Pass the thumbnail frame to the transition animator.
            guard let transitionThumbnail = transitionThumbnail, let transitionThumbnailSuperview = transitionThumbnail.superview else { return nil }

            thumbnailZoomTransitionAnimator = ZoomTransitionAnimator()
            thumbnailZoomTransitionAnimator?.thumbnailFrame = transitionThumbnailSuperview.convert(transitionThumbnail.frame, to: nil)
        }
        thumbnailZoomTransitionAnimator?.operation = operation

        return thumbnailZoomTransitionAnimator
    }

}
```

And finally when tapping a cell in the tableview, this is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)

    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as? MovieTableViewCell
    transitionThumbnail = cell?.movieImageView

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "searchToDetails", sender: indexPath.row)
}
```

My segue sends the data to the detailview in a "prepare for segue"-method.

Can anyone explain/help me what is going wrong? :-) It's as mentioned only when going back, that the view turns black.

[image]

Comment: Have you resolve your issue? I have exactly the same....

Comment: I found a solution, code available here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51617051/how-to-create-a-navigation-transition-like-the-apple-news-app

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the presenting once the animation is complete to be able to handle the toggle.

```
    { finished in
        transitionContext.completeTransition(finished)
        presenting = !presenting
    }
```

Comment: That didn't do any difference :/ But I figured, that the issue is, that when I'm going back, the main view is shrinked.. so it's actually getting smaller and smaller for every time i go to details and back.. I'm just not sure where to edit the shrinkage of the main view :/